# How to get the JSON value of the iframe？

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the iframe's document object, but I don't seem to write it right, I don't know how to get the value of json.

My picture:
[image]

My code:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myframe");

var pre_info = iframe.contentDocument.document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML;
var item_info = JSON.parse(pre_info);

console.log("object", pre_info);
```

Comment: that's not valid JSON - since the innerHTML is a STRING, you don't want the enclosing `"`

Comment: That's a rather horrible API, why is there JSON-ish stuff (it's not even real JSON) embedded in an HTML document? Ideally should never be done that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For browser compatibility use **contentWindow** with **contentDocument**(some time not supported).

Below code may solve your problem.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
var y = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument);
var pre_info = y.document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML;
var item_info = JSON.parse(pre_info.slice(1, -1));
console.log("object", pre_info);
```

Answer (score 0):

`"{"code":"400","msg":"","data":""}"`(including the wrapper double quotes) in the pre tag is not a ready-to-parse string, you should slice it with `.slice(1, -1)` to remove the double quotes and then parse it to JSON.